Does python throw away unused expressions?
In pyhon3.10, I can run this code snippet without raising any errors:
{}[0]:1

which creates an empty dictionary, and then accesses the 0 key. However, the :1 that follows is what I would consider an invalid syntax. And indeed, if I try to determine the type of the result:
type({}[0]:1)

a syntax error gets raised. A similar behavior occurs whenever I try to work with the result, such as print({}[0]:1).
Why does this happen? I am assuming that the interpreter recognizes the expression as not being assigned and does not compile it. And therefore you can run your code with the {}[0]:1 line being present. However, this is not consistent with other syntax errors being raised by different syntactically invalid code (such as 1:1 which raises an error).

If that were the right explanation, then Python would also accept type({}[0]:1), as the value isn't used either. It'd have to accept pretty much any sequence of characters at all, as any sequence of characters could be interpreted as a syntactically invalid expression whose value is unused.

{}[0]:1 as a statement is not a syntax error.
It's an annotation where {}[0] is the thing being annotated and 1 is the annotation. Normally, you would write something like x: int.
{}[0] is not an error because it is executed as if on the left-hand side of an assignment.
We can see this by using dis.dis (this is Python 3.11.2):
>>> dis.dis("{}[0]:1")
  0           0 RESUME                   0

  1           2 SETUP_ANNOTATIONS
              4 BUILD_MAP                0
              6 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
             10 POP_TOP
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             14 POP_TOP
             16 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE

Only when using {}[0]:1 as an expression, it is invalid syntax.
It's a coincidence that you chose {}[0] on the left-hand side of :, this does not always work:
>>> print(x):1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(x):1
    ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: illegal target for annotation

(You should have gotten the same error for 1:1.)
The corresponding section in the language reference is here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#annotated-assignment-statements

The LHS of an annotation is executed, and outside a function scope, so is the RHS. Note how the disassembly actually builds a dict and loads constant values of 0 and 1. It doesn't try to index the dict, because it's executing the LHS like an assignment target, not an expression - it does everything it would do for {}[0] = whatever, except the part where it would actually attempt a __setitem__ call, as there is no value to assign here.

Inside a function scope, the 1 part wouldn't be executed, but the {}[0] part would still be handled the same.

(For a typical annotation, where the LHS is just a variable, "executing the LHS as if it were an assignment target" means doing nothing, as there's none of the prep work needed for an item assignment or attribute assignment. That's why annotating an undefined variable doesn't cause problems.)

What Python version did you use? In 3.12.0 I see much less.

@nocomment: That's because of the new flow graph optimizer optimizing out the LOAD_CONST/POP_TOP pairs, as well as simplifying the ending to use the new RETURN_CONST instruction. The semantics are unchanged.
